# How to use switch case in angularjs and how can I return the value?

Tags: angularjs, switch-statement

I have created a scope like this

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller("MyController", function MyController($scope){ 
$scope.sample = [
{'NUMBER' : '1'},{'NUMBER' : '2'},{'NUMBER' : '3'},{'NUMBER' : '4'}
]
});
```

I have tried like this.In this I need to retrieve the value which is return form the switch case and to display it in a particular field.

```
<div  ng-repeat = "grp_val in sample">
<div ng-switch-on="{{grp_val.NUMBER}}">
   <div ng-switch-when="1" ng-init="value='ONE'"></div>
   <div ng-switch-when="2" ng-init="value='TWO'"></div>
   <div ng-switch-when="3" ng-init="value='THREE'"></div>
   <div ng-switch-when="4" ng-init="value='FOUR'"></div>
</div>
 <label>{{VALUE}}</label>
</div>
```

But its not working.Kindly give some solution.

Comment: what is that supposed to do? not only is it not what `ng-init` is designed for, it also won't work, for a variety of reasons; some examples of those reasons:  your variable is a different case, your variable is a primitive instead of an object, your variable is in a different scope.  Rethink your strategy here, this isn't the right way to use angular at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used `ng-repeat` for div and trying to use `ng-switch` inside `ng-repeat` which is not proper solution you are trying to implement.

Syntax for `ng-switch-on` is not proper. It should be `ng-switch` and `on=Expression`. Check the [Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch)

The way you are trying to init value using `ng-init` also not work because when code first execute, all div which have `ng-switch-when` doesn't init value and when `selected` div becomes visible, it's not init value from div because of life-cycle.

Check working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yoy3mfmw/) with working `ng-switch`